# Using the if and else statments

Tags: java, if-statement

So I have this method that display the names for any that contain a matching substring (not case-sensitive), and prints the matching names to the JTextArea. It searches for the name from an input file that has been stored as an array. But if I want to display "No results found" when the user has type in a something that does not exist in the file it then displays "No Results found" for everything, even the names that do exists. If I take the

```
 else
    displayArea.append("\n No results found");
```

statement out my method works correctly again and display the correct information. So how can I get it to display "No results found" without causing my if statement to stop working?

```
private void match(String targetSubstring)
  {
    displayArea.setText("");
    displayArea.append("FIND RESULTS for: " + targetSubstring);
    displayArea.append("\n");
    displayArea.append("\n Name               Best Decade");
    displayArea.append("\n---------------         ---------------");
    targetSubstring = targetSubstring.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
      String theName = namesArray[i].getName();
      if (theName.toUpperCase().contains(targetSubstring))
      {
        displayArea.append("\n"  + namesArray[i].getName() + "\t" + namesArray[i].bestDecade());
      }
      else 
        displayArea.append("\n No results found");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code has a logical error.

It needs to be re-written as:

```
// flag to see if any matches are found
boolean foundSomething = false;

for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
     String theName = namesArray[i].getName();
     if (theName.toUpperCase().contains(targetSubstring))
     {
         displayArea.append("\n"  + namesArray[i].getName() + "\t" + namesArray[i].bestDecade());
         foundSomething = true;
     }
}

// Now, if you didn't find anything, then add this
if (!foundSomething) { 
      displayArea.append("\n No results found");
}
```

**Reason**:
Having the else case in the for loop will append the "No results found" anytime a single index in the namesArray did not find match.

Answer (score 1):

Question is: does `namesArray` really contains `targetSubstring`? In my opinion you should start from extraction

```
if (theName.toUpperCase().contains(targetSubstring))
{
    displayArea.append("\n"  + namesArray[i].getName() + "\t" + namesArray[i].bestDecade());
}
else 
    displayArea.append("\n No results found");
```

To new method and write some simple tests – is this condition correct?

If test say that condition is OK, then you should debug this part of code and see what is wrong with data in `namesArray`. Because code looks fine at this moment.

Comment: No, there's a logical error in his loop, printing "no results found" for each element in the array not matching the substring. So the code is not entirely correct

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you're printing "no results found" for each element in the array not matching the substring. If for example the fifth element matches, but not the first four, you will print "no results found" for each of those four elements. Better add a boolean telling you if some element was found. After the loop, check if this boolean value tells you that no matching element was found. In that case, tell the user.

BTW : this wouldn't have been hard to find using a debugger.